# Ionic onesignal json data

Tags: arrays, json, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

my duyurular.ts file ;

```
export class DuyurularPage {

 duyurular: any;

 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: 
 NavParams, 
 public loadingPage: LoadingController,
 platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen)
 {

  platform.ready().then(() => {

    statusBar.styleDefault();
    splashScreen.hide();

    var notificationOpenedCallback = (jsonData) =>  {
      this.duyurular = jsonData.notification.payload;
      alert(this.duyurular);
    };

    alert
    window["plugins"].OneSignal
    .startInit("ASDQWEQWE", "ASDFQW123")
    .handleNotificationOpened(notificationOpenedCallback)
    .endInit();
  });

}
```

my duyurular.html file

```
  <ion-card class="card-background-page" *ngFor="let item of duyurular">
<ion-item>
  <ion-avatar item-start>
    <img src="./assets/img/avatar.png">
  </ion-avatar>
  <h2>{{duyurular.title}}</h2>
</ion-item>
<ion-card-content>{{item.body}}</ion-card-content>
```

ı can alert(item.title) but not write duyurular.title in duyurular.html.

What do I have to do to show in duyurular.html pages duyurular.title and duyurular.body ?

Comment: are you getting errors? you have `*ngFor="let item of duyurular"` which suggests `duyurular` is an array. But `duyurular.title` suggests it is an object

Comment: ı doing {{item.title]] but same. I can't see getting errors but building time don' t show errors.

Comment: `alert(this.duyurular);` what does it show?

Comment: `{object} {object}` but `alert(this.duyurular.title)` show my notification' s body.

Comment: try: `alert(JSON.stringify(this.duyurular));`

Comment: show `{"notificaionID":"asdqweqwads",title":"aşsdqlweqwle qqwp "body":"sa",.......... notification json data .... } ` my notification jsons payload :{all data} show.

Comment: are you trying to display a list of notifications? that is not an array

Comment: [alert(JSON.stringify(this.duyurular)); screenshot](https://ibb.co/iWoATG) this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not getting an array of notifications. So currently `duyurular` is not an array and the `*ngFor` in your HTML will not work.

```
export class DuyurularPage {

 duyurular: any[]=[];//declare as array and preferably set as empty.

//...In your callback,
 var notificationOpenedCallback = (jsonData) =>  {
      this.duyurular.push(jsonData.notification.payload);//push into the array.
      alert(this.duyurular);
    };
```

Comment: u are a king man! Thank u so much :) But when I closed my app, duyurular array vanish. How to do permanent array ?

Comment: no problem: ) for that you might want to consider some sort of storage solution like ionic-storage or localstorage etc..

Comment: Okey ı doing ionic storage, again thank you so much :) have a good day :)